# Show Gtk.Popover at cursor of Gtk.Entry

Tags: c, gtk, vala

I want to to show a `Gtk.Popover` at the position of the cursor of a `Gtk.Entry`. I'm only only able to add the popover relative to the entry itself, but the `Gtk.Popover` appears at the center of the `Gtk.Entry` everytime.

Is there a way how I can get the position of my `Gtk.Entry` cursor and create the popover at this position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the widget to which your popover is relative to, by using [`Gtk.Popover.relative_to`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Popover.relative_to.html); then you can use [`Gtk.Popover.pointing_to`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Popover.pointing_to.html) and the rectangle with the location of the cursor. To get that, use [`Gtk.Entry.cursor_position`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Entry.cursor_position.html) to retrieve the index of the cursor in characters and transform it into a location within the Pango.Layout of the `Gtk.Entry` widget; if the entry is allowed to scroll, you should also get the `Gtk.Entry.scroll_offset` and subtract it from the coordinates returned by Pango.